# How to change where git repos are stored on SSH server

Tags: git, ssh

I'm using an SSH server to host some git repos. A repo on the server will have a url like `git@git.example.com:repo-name.git`. By default, it takes the name of the repo  and looks for a folder by that name  in the `git` user's home folder. For example, the url `git@git.example.com:repo-name.git` would resolve to `/home/git/repo-name.git/`.

I'd like to store the repo contents on the server in a different location, such as `/srv`. That would mean that the above url would instead resolve to `/srv/git/repo-name.git/`. How can I change the server to look for repos in the place I want? Is there a git or ssh config setting that controls the folder where git/ssh looks for repo contents?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming from the paths you're posting above that this is a Linux or BSD server. I am also assuming that you have admin access to the server, since you're talking about changing the locations of folders.

The best way I can think of to do this would be to add a new **bind** mount point in your `/etc/fstab` file. By doing so, you can create two locations in which you can access this same folder.

As an example,

```
/home/git /srv/git-repos none defaults,bind 0 0
```

will create a mount point at `/home/git` that is actually housed at `/srv/git-repos`. For all intents and purposes, they are essentially the same location.

For more information on this concept, you should browse through the [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) man page, specifically the "Bind mount operation" section.